# Contiki-ng: sniff neighbour packets in Cooja and respond/send like normal node

Tags: contiki, cooja, contiki-ng

I run the example of rpl-udp with udp-server and udp-client. I want to enable udp-client to sniff packets from neighbour nodes, but at the same time allow it to behave like a normal node. How is that possible? I added the NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, 0) which disables the RADIO_RX_MODE_ADDRESS_FILTER (makes it 0) but when I simulate in Cooja (using z1) the nodes don't sniff all packets. Also, I get many duplicate warnings like below:

```
00:57.609 ID:7 [WARN: CSMA] drop duplicate link layer packet from c10c.0000.0000.0004, seqno 114
```

Is there any other flag to allow sniff of all packets and reduce the duplicate packets?

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
I tried this solution here https://sourceforge.net/p/contiki/mailman/message/34888182/ but I face the same problem (have many retransmissions and duplicate packets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that, there is no promiscious mode for Contiki-NG MAC protocols. The packets addressed to other nodes are filtered out at the CSMA level, even if the radio receives them.

The way to implement sniffer is to either to work with NETSTACK_RADIO directly, to make your own MAC, or to hack the `input_packet` function of the CSMA MAC.

Comment: Why there is no promiscious mode for contiki-ng? Isn't similar to contiki-os implementation? I look to implement sniff but also normal operation of node at the same time without dropping any packets.

Comment: @phrick Contiki-NG does not have this functionality because Contiki does not have it. Or am I wrong - what makes you think that Contiki does?

Comment: yes check here https://sourceforge.net/p/contiki/mailman/message/34888182/ they do it in contiki-os but I get retransmissions and doesn't sniff all packets.

Comment: @phrick the thread clearly says that the approach did not work for the user ands someone suggests that the framer code must be modified to achieve what he wanted. When they talk about promiscious mode, it's actually at the radio driver's level, which you already have figured out how to enable, but is not sufficient.

Comment: if you can tell me more about how to achieve this by changing the CSMA MAC layer I will close this question. Thank you.

Comment: @phrick I provided you some suggestions here. Writing the exact code is too much for a SO answer, sorry.